# Uploading a file in Selenium

Tags: java, file, selenium, upload

I want to upload two image (.png) files .I used action keys and send keys  to upload the file.It is working fine for one file but if again i want to upload second image file,the file is not getting uploaded.

```
Actions action1 = new Actions(m.driver); 
action1.moveToElement(m.driver.findElement(By.id("onetidIOFile"))).click(); 
WebElement s=m.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
s.sendKeys("path of one file");m.click("xpath", ".//[@id='attachOKbutton']"); 
m.click("id", "Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Actions.AttachFile-Large"); 
action1.moveToElement(m.drive‌​r.findElement(By.id("onetidIOFile"))).click(); 
m.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//‌​input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("path of second file "); 
m.key("Enter","attachOKbutton");
```

Can anyone help me in doing this???

Comment: Add your code and the html.

Comment: Don't paste code as comment, edit your question instead

Answer (score 0):

@sajju - You can update your code as below:

It should work as it is working for me. And give your test method priority as per your requirement. Just for Example I gave priority here as @Test(priority = 1). I hope it should work for you.

```
 @Test(priority = 1)
    public void CERTIFICATIONSSCREENUploadCertficationFilesValidation()
            throws InterruptedException, AWTException {

        //Click on File Upload Button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='certificationFile']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        // Set the file name in the clipboard. Also following line of code will search file in your computer so make sure you provide correct file path.

        StringSelection s = new StringSelection("C:\\Doc\\CertificationFile.xls");
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(s, null);
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        Robot robot1 = new Robot();
        robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
```

}